# Cannot get nodejs 5.x installed on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, nodejs

Using the software manager it automatically installs a very old version, v0.10.25. I am following this instructions from this [link](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall):

```
Node.js v5.x:

NOTE: If you are using Ubuntu Precise or Debian Wheezy, you might want to read about running Node.js >= 4.x on older distros.
# Using Ubuntu
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

When I run run the first line it ends with:

```
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Fetched 821 B in 19s (41 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.puppetlabs.com/dists/lucid/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.puppetlabs.com/dists/lucid/dependencies/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/trusty/dists/node_5.1.0/main/source/Sources  HttpError404

W: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/trusty/dists/node_5.1.0/main/binary-amd64/Packages  HttpError404

W: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/trusty/dists/node_5.1.0/main/binary-i386/Packages  HttpError404

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.puppetlabs.com/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.puppetlabs.com/dists/lucid/dependencies/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.puppetlabs.com/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.puppetlabs.com/dists/lucid/dependencies/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Error executing command, exiting
```

Then I end up with an older version of nodejs when I run the apt-get command. I am stumped...the manual installation did the same thing. I am not too savy at linux, but is there another way? Can I just download the correct version from their website and install it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply download nodejs latest from https://nodejs.org/en/. untar and ungzip it using

```
tar xzf file.tar.gz
```

you can save the folder where you keep your installables (like /opt or /usr/share). finally, link two most important executables "node" and "npm" stored at /bin/ or simply run it from there.

I found this most convenient. If you face any issue let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Node.js on the development environment, try [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

It is very easy to install and switch multiple versions of Node.js.